Feed GTK File Chooser Dialogue with recently visited directories from zshz database
Often, I find myself performing tasks in the zsh shell and later needing to open or save a file using the GTK File Chooser dialogue in a GUI application, typically located in a directory I recently accessed via zsh.
Within zsh, I utilize zsh-z to efficiently navigate to recently accessed directories.
Is there a method to integrate the information stored in the zsh-z database, maintaining the same sorting, into the recently visited directories list displayed in the GTK File Chooser?
Alternatively, if there exists a system-wide replacement for the GTK File Chooser that better accommodates this workflow, I am open to exploring alternative solutions.
Edit
I just found out that the other way around (which is also very useful) seems to work like described here.
So to do what I want, it seems to be enough to feed the file ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel with the content of the zshz database somehow...
